# Kronecker sum or direct sum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

When we write $$H=\sum_k H_k$$ in condensed matter physics, are we using [Kronecker sum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckerSum.html) or [direct sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition#Direct_sum)?

I think this is direct sum. However, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) says it is Kronecker sum.

Can anyone give some physics context where these two sums are used, to help me distinguish them?

Comment: Does $k$ label different particles? In that case, one should use Kronecker sum. Using direct sum would mean that different particles correspond to orthogonal quantum states.

Comment: k means wave number after Fourier transform of a lattice. Your comment is interesting, I am not understand yet. Can you expand it?

Comment: What's $H$? A Hilbert space? Some operator? Some more context would definitely help.

Comment: Different sectors (usually distinguished by quantum numbers) of a **single system** are combined using the direct sum. On the other hand, suppose that there are **multiple systems** and that we are interested in an additive physical quantity (e.g., energy). Then, the corresponding operator for the total system is given by the Kronecker sum of the operators for constituent subsystems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is definitely a Kronecker sum. Take the case where there are only two different states $+$ and $-$, then, for example,
$$ \hat H =E_+ \hat a^\dagger_+ \hat a_++E_- \hat a^\dagger_- \hat a_- .$$

What does $\hat a_+$ means ? Well, if we label the states with the number of excitations in the states $+$ and $-$ by $|n_+,n_-\rangle$, then we understand $\hat a_+|n_+,n_-\rangle$ as $\sqrt{n_+}|n_+-1,n_-\rangle$, which really means mathematicaly $\hat a_+ \otimes 1_-|n_+\rangle \otimes |n_-\rangle=(\sqrt{n_+}+ \times1_+)\otimes 1_-|n_+\rangle \otimes |n_-\rangle$, and thus 
$$ \hat H =E_+ \hat a^\dagger_+ \hat a_+\otimes 1_-+E_- 1_+\otimes \hat a^\dagger_- \hat a_-.$$

This is indeed a Kronecker sum.